# Gradle sync failed in android studio 3.6

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Gradle sync failed: Don't know how to build models for org.gradle.tooling.internal.gradle.DefaultGradleBuild@61cdce4

```
**// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.**

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/" }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.graphhopper.android"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {

        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile(group: 'com.graphhopper', name: 'graphhopper-core', version: '0.9-SNAPSHOT') {
       exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
       exclude group: 'org.openstreetmap.osmosis', module: 'osmosis-osm-binary'
       exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', module: 'xmlgraphics-commons'
    }

    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm:0.6.0'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0:natives-armeabi'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0:natives-armeabi-v7a'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0:natives-x86'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-jts:0.6.0'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-themes:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'
    compile 'com.vividsolutions:jts:1.13'

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.21'
}
```

I am using android studio 3.6. I am not able to build the project. I tried to invalidate caches/Restart but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the class path to latest version and check

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
```

to

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()       //add here
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()      //and here also
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}
```

Build.gradle(app:)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.graphhopper.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {

        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile(group: 'com.graphhopper', name: 'graphhopper-core', version: '0.9-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
        exclude group: 'org.openstreetmap.osmosis', module: 'osmosis-osm-binary'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', module: 'xmlgraphics-commons'
    }

    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm:0.6.0'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0:natives-armeabi'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0:natives-armeabi-v7a'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0:natives-x86'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-jts:0.6.0'
    compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-themes:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'
    compile 'com.vividsolutions:jts:1.13'

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.21'
}
```

Comment: Getting this error:    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.jar
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified

Comment: Build file '/home/volcano/Pictures/Navigation/GrassHopper-API-master/android/build.gradle' line: 4
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

Comment: Now i am getting this error:   MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

Comment: Getting this:   ERROR: Cannot invoke method targetCompatibility() on null object
Open File

Comment: Where can i share?

Comment: I have shared both build.gradle(project),build.gradle(app)  code in the link

Comment: Same error: ERROR: Cannot invoke method targetCompatibility() on null object
Open File

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211352/discussion-between-android-id-and-black4guy).

Comment: I resolved the problem by adding this line in  build.gradle(Project):       maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

Comment: okay. glad if my answer helped you please accept answer so it may help others. thanku

Answer (score 0):

Your **build.gradle (Module:app)** should look like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.graphhopper.android"
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 22
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }

        lintOptions {

            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }
    }



    dependencies {
        compile(group: 'com.graphhopper', name: 'graphhopper-core', version: '0.9-SNAPSHOT') {
            exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
            exclude group: 'org.openstreetmap.osmosis', module: 'osmosis-osm-binary'
            exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', module: 'xmlgraphics-commons'
        }

        compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm:0.6.0'
        compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0'
        compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0:natives-armeabi'
        compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0:natives-armeabi-v7a'
        compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-android:0.6.0:natives-x86'
        compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-jts:0.6.0'
        compile 'org.mapsforge:vtm-themes:0.6.0'
        compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'
        compile 'com.vividsolutions:jts:1.13'

        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.21'
}
```

Your **build.gradle (Module:project)** should look like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.**

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/" }
    }
}
```

And your **gradle-wrapper.properties** should be like this

```
#Mon Feb 10 21:12:29 YEKT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Comment: Getting this error after made changes as suggested:   Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
     - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.pom
     - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.jar
     Required by:
     project :

Comment: From View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle, Make sure **Toogle Offline mode** is not checked, right next to settings icon.

Comment: Nope, it is not checked.

Comment: Try downgrading your classpath in **build.gradle (Project module)** to 
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3`

Comment: File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle. Make sure *Use Gadle from* is selected to *gradle-wrapper.properties*